# OutOfMemoryError GC overhead limit exceeded for java jdbc preparedStatement

Tags: java, jdbc, out-of-memory, prepared-statement

I'm writing a tool used for transferring the data from old schema to new schema in oracle database.

There are about twenty tables in my database. Only two of them are big, they may have four million records. Others are small ( maybe ten thousands or one hundred thousand).

Now I use one thread to process all small tables in serially, and divide big table into pieces, create some thread, and use one thread process one piece, every piece is one million record.

Now I have some problems. When I start the program, every is ok. But when my program run after a period of time, I will get some error info:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-8" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBlobInputStream.needBytes(OracleBlobInputStream.java:168)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.readInternal(OracleBufferedStream.java:178)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:147)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleBufferedStream.read(OracleBufferedStream.java:137)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.BlobAccessor.getBytes(BlobAccessor.java:249)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getBytes(OracleResultSetImpl.java:714)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getBytes(OracleResultSet.java:1625)
at datatransfer.processor.CProcessor.write(CProcessor.java:111)
at datatransfer.processor.Processor.process(Processor.java:77)
at datatransfer.thread.CThread.run(CThread.java:37)
```

I have checked my program, there is no closed loop, and I really close `statement` and `resultset`.

Every `Thread` has its own `Connection`.

How can I check the reason why my program cost memory? And is there any way to solve this problem?

```
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    int count = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while(rsSrc.next()){
        preStatement.setString(1, rsSrc.getString(1)); 
        preStatement.setString(2, rsSrc.getString(2)); 
        preStatement.setString(3, rsSrc.getString(3)); 
        preStatement.setString(4, rsSrc.getString(4)); 
        preStatement.setString(5, rsSrc.getString(5)); 
        preStatement.setString(6, rsSrc.getString(6)); 
        preStatement.addBatch();
        count++;
        if (count % batchSize == 0){
            preStatement.executeBatch();
            preStatement.clearBatch();

        }
    }
    preStatement.executeBatch();
    preStatement.clearBatch();
    writeConn.commit();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

`statement` and `preStatement` are created by different `Connection`, one is old schema, the other is new schema.

Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: Try running your app with -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError jvm arg that will spit out the heap dump and you can then analyze your heap on profiler. Try increasing your heap -Xmx3G if its too low.

Comment: Why? You can do everything you need with the workbench and SQL commands. You don't need Java for this, let alone JDBC, `PreparedStatement`, and all the rest of it. And all this multithreading is a complete waste of your time. The disk isn't multithreaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try to analyse the instances / object creation in your RAM with jvisualvm, it usually tells you right away if you are leaking or not. (It's a GUI, do not panic ;-) )

Doc -> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html

It's a profiler, so it will show you where you spend time, how many instances of your classes you have and basically what's going on IN your app while it is running.

It's installed by default with the official oracle jdk on linux!

If the memory usage is almost constant but on the edge, try to increase you heap (-Xmx2G for example)

Answer (score 1):

For my instance, I had to fire hundreds of thousands `INSERT` statements from **Matlab** into the DB. I also got the GC overhead exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

My solution was, to close the DB connection every some thousand(in this case 2000) INSERT shots, delete and clear the object from the Matlab workspace. Of course, to subsequently open a new connection.

```
classdef MySqlService < handle    
    properties
        db;
        counter = 0;
        dblimit = 0;
    end    
    methods
        function x = executeQuery(obj, query)
            obj.counter = obj.counter + 1;
            if (obj.counter > obj.dblimit + 2000)
                obj.dblimit = obj.counter;
                
                delete(obj.db);
                clear obj.db;                
                import lib.queryMySQL.src.edu.stanford.covert.db.MySQLDatabase;
                obj.db = MySQLDatabase('localhost:3306', 'fani_dev', 'root', 'dev1');
            end
            obj.db.prepareStatement(query);
            x = obj.db.query();
        end
        function obj = MySqlService()
            import lib.queryMySQL.src.edu.stanford.covert.db.MySQLDatabase;
            obj.db = MySQLDatabase('localhost:3306', 'fani_dev', 'root', 'dev1');
        end
    end    
end
```

Script works now without problems. Also CPU workload and RAM usage seems good.

Comment: This answer is in Matlab language, however the same does apply to Java directly. By following this advice my program dropped from 1GB ram at 1min after start to 56mb. Looping and preparing statements makes it grow like a snowball. Opening and closing connections might take you a little more time in processing, but it keeps ram and GC at bay.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution of the problem is just increasing the heap size available for Eclipse. You can do so as you open eclipse.ini file which is located on your eclipse installation folder.

After opening the file you can add -Xmx2048M which will provide 2 GB of heap available to your Eclipse.

This solution depends of how powerful is your system and how much of the whole heap you can give to Eclipse.

[For more information click here...](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F)

---

Another way to handle the problem is to try process smaller pieces(chunks) for the big tables.

---

If you want to seek deeper and found the concrete reason for the OOM you can create a Heap Dump (or a few heap dumps) and analyze it using http://www.eclipse.org/mat/ which SAP and IBM for free. It is a really powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have use analysis tools to check the heap and I find that when the cost of memory will increase with the program running. Could `PreparedStatement.executeBatch()` cause this problem? I will try to use small pieces to process the big tables.

Comment: It is normal to observe increasing of the memoryused with the program running. What's more interesting is to see exactly which objects allocate most of the memory. Those objects would be the memory leak you are seeking.